# How to customize TextArea in MVC Razor View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a TextArea generated using razor, I would like to change its HTML properties. For example, I would like to change the number of rows

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Desc{ get; set; }

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Desc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite tricky with `EditorFor`, since it can generate very different HTML depending on the type of the property.

Here, since you know what you want, I'd use `@Html.TextAreaFor`, then you can pass HTML attributes like this:

```
@Html.TexAreaFor (x => x.Desc, new {style="width: 200px"});
```

Note: the most common attribute to want to set is `class` for the CSS class. The problem is we're actually writing C# here and `class` is a C# keyword. We have to escape it with `@` (which is actually the C# verbatim symbol, not the Razor symbol):

```
@Html.TexAreaFor (x => x.Desc, new {@class="some-css-class"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, what about the Rows property?

Comment: Not a C# keyword, so nothing special. Just comma separate for multiple attributes:

`new {rows="40", cols="50"}`

Comment: If you're happy, please mark this as a correct answer - thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use class and style attribute like below

```
@Html.TextArea("myTextArea", "This is value", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Desc, new { @class = "required", style = " rows=10, columns=40" })
```

Comment: Thank you, but the rows and columns worked out of the style attribute

Comment: The style version is wrong. Remember, style should contain CSS, but 1) `rows` is not a CSS property. `columns` is, but means something entirely different and doesn't take an integer. 2) CSS uses `:` not `=`